# Show Images from SD card in a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-sdcard

I made a small app which can read the images from the SD card and shows them in a GridView.

The problem is that I tried to run the app on the two phones I have, one running Android 4.1.2 and another one running Android 5.0.2.

It ran fine on the phone with 4.1.2, but it is crashing on the other one.
It is also not running on the emulator.

I don't know why.

This is my Gallery.java file

```
public class Gallery extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView gv;
    ArrayList<File> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

        list= imageReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() );

        gv= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView );
        gv.setAdapter(new GridAdapter());

        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewImage.class ).putExtra("img",list.get(position ).toString() ));

            }
        });
    }

    class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size() ;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position ) ;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.single_grid, parent, false );
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse( getItem(position).toString()) );

            return convertView ;
        }
    }

    ArrayList<File> imageReader(File root){
        ArrayList<File> a = new ArrayList<>() ;
        File[] files = root.listFiles() ;
        for(int i=0; i<files.length ; i++)
        {
            if(files[i].isDirectory() ){
                a.addAll(imageReader(files[i]) );

            }
            else{
                if(files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")){
                    a.add(files[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

This is the ViewImage.java file

```
public class ViewImage extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView iv2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_image);

        //Intent i = getIntent() ;
        //File f = (File)i.getExtras().getParcelable("img");
        String f = getIntent().getStringExtra("img");
        iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        iv2.setImageURI( Uri.parse( f));
    }
}
```

I request the following permission in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Have to post your `logcat` error

Comment: `File[] files = root.listFiles() ;`. Check if `files` is null.